# Could not get shipping countries from commerce js

Tags: reactjs

```js
const { countries } = await commerce.services.localeListShippingCountries(checkoutTokenId);
```

it does not fetches shipping countries
i get empty array in countries restructured element

Answer (score 0):

You can change it with

```
const { countries }=await commerce.services.localeListCountries().then((checkoutTokenId) => console.log('checkout Token Id >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>',checkoutTokenId));
```

it works for me